# Invoke AWS SNS Topic from SQL trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

We want to invoke a AWS SNS TOPIC and with some data using SQS table trigger. In MySQL we have **mysql.lambda_async("topic arn")** but how is it possible from SQL. Please give your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.Lambda.html), the parameters for `lambda_async` are actually the Lambda function ARN and a JSON payload.

Example from the documentation:

```
SELECT lambda_sync(
'arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:868710585169:function:BasicTestLambda', 
'{"operation": "ping"}');
```

You can't directly connect SNS to SQL triggers, but you could trigger a Lambda function that publishes the data to an SNS topic or pushes it to an SQS queue.

Comment: Seems to be an answer for my question, Let me try this I will get back with my results.

Comment: lambda_sync is not for sql server right? I am looking similar for SQL server.